# Highcharts Omits X Axis Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a demo of the problem chart [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/DNREz/).

Here is the code that I am using to generate the highchart.  When the chart renders, it cuts off option2 of the x axis label?  What would be causing this?

I'm not using the step parameter, so there shouldn't be any reason to skip the label... It renders find with the mouseover event to display the category name when you hover over the bar, but it won't display the category name next to the bar.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
$(function () {
    prchart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'prcont23',
            type: 'bar',
            width: 300,
            height: 180
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test results'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['option1', 'option2', 'opt3'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: '0 Total Votes',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'vote test',
            data: [20, 50, 1000]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
height: 180
```

I can reproduce your issues on Chrome, and I fixed it by either removing "height: 180" or assigning a bigger value, so I think your label are hidden because of insufficient height. If you have 4 points, then the 2nd and 3rd will get hidden with that height.

Answer (score 0):

It's known bug of 3.0.7 version for Highcharts. Already resolved on master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/DNREz/1/

Master taken from:

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's weird. I'm getting the opposite results. When I use version 3.0.7 I see all the labels but when I use newer versions the labels are not all showing up: http://jsfiddle.net/h2umP/

Comment: Highcharts won't set higher left margin, so will hide labels. You can set for example 110px left margin to make sure there will be enough space. Also try to use formatter with fixed width for labels.

Comment: I opened an issue with highcharts and they suggested a couple other workarounds https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2642